# an alternative to Enumerable.First (System.Linq) C#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, .net-2.0

I have this piece of code running in .net 3.5

```
public const string SvgNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
public const string XLinkPrefix = "xlink";
public const string XLinkNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
public const string XmlNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace";

public static readonly List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Namespaces = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("", SvgNamespace),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>(XLinkPrefix, XLinkNamespace),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("xml", XmlNamespace)
};

private bool _inAttrDictionary;
private string _name;
private string _namespace;

public string NamespaceAndName
        {
            get
            {
                if (_namespace == SvgNamespace)
                    return _name;
                return Namespaces.First(x => x.Value == _namespace).Key + ":" + _name;
            }
        }
```

and I am currently converting it to .net 2.0 (removing System.Linq). How can I maintain the functionality of **Enumerable.First Method (IEnumerable, Func)** found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050(v=vs.110).aspx) within my code?

Full source [file](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG/blob/master/Source/SvgAttributeAttribute.cs)

Comment: What is _Namespaces_ ? There is no variable with this name here

Comment: @Steve, there is one `public static readonly List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Namespaces`

Comment: @Rahul I see it now, but in my excuse, if you look at the source code in the link posted the things gets really confusing.

Comment: @Steve, LOL, did you actually browse into that source code link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use a `foreach` loop like

```
foreach(var item in Namespaces)
{
  if(item.Value == _namespace)
    return item.Key + ":" + _name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can create GetFirst method as follows:

```
    public string NamespaceAndName
    {
        get
        {
            if (_namespace == SvgNamespace)
                return _name;

            return GetFirst(Namespaces, _namespace).Key + ":" + _name;
        }
    }
    private KeyValuePair<string, string> GetFirst(List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> namespaces,string yourNamespaceToMatch)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < namespaces.Count; i++)
        {
            if (namespaces[i].Value == yourNamespaceToMatch)
                return namespaces[i];
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains no matching element");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not really an alternative to `Enumerable.First`, but since you have actually a `List<T>` variable, you can consider [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx) method. The signature is compatible with the `Enumerable.First`, but note that the behavior is compatible with `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`, i.e. in case the element doesn't exist, you'll get NRE instead of the "Sequence contains no matching element".

```
return Namespaces.Find(x => x.Value == _namespace).Key + ":" + _name;
```

Comment: I like your answer as well.